# How To Sort inside a Tuple (SQL)

Tags: sql

I want to get an answer which a table has two column and many rows. For each row, I want two column shown in some order, for example:

initial table:

```
+-----------+---------+
| nameA     | nameB   |
+-----------+---------+
| Ca        | Us      | 
| Db        | Ac      |  
+-----------+---------+

The target table is:

+-----------+---------+
| nameA     | nameB   |
+-----------+---------+
| Ca        | Us      | 
| Ac        | Db      |  
+-----------+---------+
```

How to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
SELECT
    (CASE WHEN nameA <= nameB THEN nameA
    ELSE nameB END) AS field1,
    (CASE WHEN nameA < nameB THEN nameB
    ELSE nameA END) AS field2
FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Marco's, but using `greatest` and `least` functions:

```
SELECT
    least(nameA,nameB) AS field1,
    greatest(nameA,nameB) AS field2
FROM your_table
```

Comment: If you are using proprietary SQL, please state the product you are assuming.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then the following update should swap the names where name B is 'lower than' name A.

```
UPDATE table
SET nameA = nameB, nameB = nameA
WHERE nameB < nameA;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT nameA, nameB 
  FROM YourTable 
 WHERE nameA <= nameB 
UNION
SELECT nameB AS nameA, nameA AS nameB
  FROM YourTable 
 WHERE nameB < nameA;
```